# Identify names of metrics from view

Tags: google-analytics

I need to query the Google Analytics API to reproduce the following view:
[image]

In my Python code I have a list of dimensions and metrics that I want to query:

```
'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:productListClicks'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:landingPagePath'}],
```

My problem is that I do not know the name of the columns in the format 'ga:...' and in the Query Explorer there are multiple names for a given column.

Is there a way to see the name of the columns in the format 'ga:...' directly in GA?

If not, how can I find the right names?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the GA query builder, you can use the type ahead/search feature of the tool to find these attributes.

You'll find the query explorer here:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

This is what it looks like when you find these:
[image]

Some of the ones you're looking for are:
ga:impressions
ga:adClicks
ga:CTR
ga:sessions
ga:bounceRate

etc.

The benefit of doing this in the query builder, is you can then test it before going back to python. There are a lot of complications of mixing metrics and dimensions, and making sure what you're doing is valid here first will save headaches!